# How to figure out if range is allowed without accept-ranges header

Tags: java, header

I'm trying to create a multi-threaded downloader application. For this, I get `InputStream`s like this:

```
URLConnection cn = new URL(str).openConnection();
cn.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + first + "-" + last);
cn.connect();
cn.getInputStream();
```

I check `Accept-Ranges` header if it is allowed to request a part of the file. I've found that `Accept-Ranges: none` means it's not allowed, but sometimes the header doesn't even contain `Accept-Ranges` field. Are there any other ways to check if the connection supports ranges? For example checking if the length of returned part is equal to `last - first + 1` or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request two different ranges, read first N bytes to buffers, and compare them. I think 8192 bytes would be enough.

```
boolean doesAcceptRanges(String str)
{
    URLConnection cn1 = new URL(str).openConnection();
    cn1.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + 0 + "-" + 8192);
    cn1.connect();
    InputStream input1 = cn1.getInputStream();
    URLConnection cn2 = new URL(str).openConnection();
    cn2.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + 8193+ "-" + 16385);
    cn2.connect();
    InputStream input2 = cn2.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer1 = new byte[8192];
    byte[] buffer2 = new byte[8192];
    input1.read(buffer1);
    input2.read(buffer2);
    if(Arrays.equals(buffer1, buffer2))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```